# Evento focus no funciona Jquery en Chrome

Tags: jquery, function

aprendo jquery. Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
$("#nombre").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid pink");
    });
```

y mi codigo HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" /> 
</form>
```

Pero al dar click en el input en navegador Chrome no funciona. Y su utilizo Firefox si funciona sin problema alguno.
En chrome SOLO al hacer clic fuera del input lo pinta rosa. Y en firefox al hacer clic dentro del input lo hace, lo que es lo correcto comoi firefox lo hace
Alguna idea?

Tengo jquery;     js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js

Comment: Debería de funcionarte sin problema, eh testeado tu código en mi PC con Chrome y funciona correctamente, intenta agregar el evento **blur** a ese mismo elemento y agrega los estilos como al inicio.

Comment: El código funciona sin problema alguno, solo has esto: `outline: none;`

Comment: En la pregunta que marco como duplicada esta la solución planteada en el comentario anterior

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```js
$("#nombre").on('focus', function(){
    $(this).css("outline", "unset");
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid pink");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" /> 
</form>
```

Chrome por default te pone esta regla en los focus:

> :focus {
> outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px; }

con la siguiente linea la idea es quitar este estilo que te pone por default en el outline

> $(this).css("outline", "unset");

Answer (score 0):

Hola como ya lo mencionaron el problema es con la propiedad `outline` de css, también se puede tener el mismo efecto solo con **CSS**, y si quieres solo hacerlo con **Jquery** también puedes usar el método focusout para restablecer el valor del border original.

Ejemplo con **Jquery**:

```js
$("#nombre").focus(function(){
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid pink");
});

$("#nombre").focusout(function(){
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid salmon");
});
```

```css
#nombre {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" /> 
</form>
```

Ejemplo con **CSS**:

```css
#nombre {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid salmon;
}

#nombre:focus {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" /> 
</form>
```